# Create new route Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a problem:
I want do decrement the quantity of a product of a line_item
I use a button_to to decrement the quantity (the cart will be updated by AJAX)
Btw , i' m not able to create a new action in the controller of line_items.
I created the new action "less" and i added the new route

```
resources :line_items do
    post :less, on: :member     
end
```

in the routes.rb file. But it doen't work.
i have this error:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError

No route matches {:action=>"less", :controller=>"line_items", :product_id=>7} missing required keys: [:id]

Can you help me? Thx all :)

here my code.

View:

<%= button_to '-', less_line_item_path(product_id: line_item.product_id), remote: true %>

In line_items Controller:

```
...
def less
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.less_items(product.id)
    respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to store_url}
            #a respond_to passiamo il blocco con la @current_item
            #si passa un blocco perchè è definito cosi il metodo
            format.js   { @current_item = @line_item} 
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

...
```

In cart model:

```
def less_items(product_id)  
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item && current_item > 1
        current_item.quantity -= 1
    else
        #don't do nothing
    end
    current_item
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have no `:id` field.

Change the button_to to...

```
<%= button_to '-', less_line_item_path(line_item, product_id: line_item.product_id), remote: true %>
```

That will pass the line_item id in the `:id` params and the routing will be happy.

Comment: When you have a "member" route, it works for a particular instance of the class, so it expects to have the id of a particular object.  You can do `less_line_item_path(line_item.id, product_id: line_item.product_id)` to pass the id, but if you pass the object itself the id is extracted automatically.  If you had made it a "collection" route then you wouldn't need to specify an object to get an object id as that would work without a specific id.

Comment: umm ok i understand but if i put :collection i have this error: undefined method `less_line_item_path' for #<#<Class:0x546b508>:0x546a950>

Comment: Because if it's a `:collection` (for possibly many line_items) you need to use the plural... `less_line_items_path`

Comment: Yes, now the error disapears but my function doen't work. Can you see if there is something wrong? thx very much

Comment: in the console i see :  NoMethodError undefined method less_items

Comment: Where did you define `@cart` ?  If you don't have that defined then `@cart.less_items` will give you undefined method less_items for nil::NilClass

Comment: i use:     before_action :set_cart, only: [:create,:less]    but i think this is not the problem

Comment: i think the routing is bad cause if i wrote into the less action only puts "DEBUG" i don t see it in the console..maybe it doesn't enter

Comment: How can your `set_cart` method work?  Do you have the cart id in a session variable?  If your problem is `NoMethoderror undefined method less_items for nil::NilClass` and if that's the only place in your controller you're calling the `less_items` method, then the action `less` is definitely being called.  It sounds like you have a different problem, you may want to post a new question.

Comment: Use the `pry` gem and insert a `binding.pry` line in the action to inspect the values of your variables in the console.

Comment: i ll write a new question. Thx for all :) you are very gentle